# How to draw a circle ring

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I would like to draw a circle ring in react-native project. I would like the circle ring component be customised in its size when using it. Here is what I tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

const Ring = ({size}) => {
  return (
      <View
        style={[styles.circle, {width: size, height: size}]}
      />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderWidth: 15,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default Ring;
```

When I use my `Ring` component, like this:

```
const MyScreen = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Ring size={6} />
        <Text>XYZ</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingVertical: 17,
    paddingHorizontal: 36,
  },
});
export default MyScreen;
```

it however shows a filled circle instead of a ring shape. How can I have a circle ring?

Comment: Reduce the borderWidth it should work

Comment: No, it doesn't. Tried. Reducing borderWidth only shows smaller filled circle.

Comment: i changed the size to 20 and it worked, https://snack.expo.io/9CquoYZ09

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't work for me. Let me also show my code where I use the Ring component. Just a sec.

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan could you please try the `<Ring>` with my updated code, whether it works for you?

Comment: Ok, you said `20` for borderWidth above, that's why it doesn't work. I changed to `2` it works. Thanks!

Comment: i said size 20 and with is something like 2

Comment: I updated the snack with borderWidth:2 can you refresh n see

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. You could make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is having a higher value for the borderWidth.
You can change the styles like below

```
  circle: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
```

Or have a dyanamic value for borderWidth and others like below

```
const Ring = ({ size }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.circle,
        {
          width: size,
          height: size,
          borderRadius: size / 2,
          borderWidth: (size * 5) / 100,
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

Calculating the boderRadius would help when the size is over 50 and will always produce a circle.